# dont know what happened but my joomla 2.5 blog has black background?

Tags: joomla, background, blogs

I am not a programmer or site designer and I have searched everywhere for a solution.  My website template works fine but my blog page is black background.  There is black background in the template but all pages have a white background in the body.  Only the first page you see when you click the blog menu item is black.  Please help.  website is www.tfabfitness.com

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it your content on your blog page is contained by the CSS class `bgblackbottom`. This class is for your footer, and as youcan see on that page it does not span the full width. The divs are not placed correctly and should be setup as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
     <div class="blog""> 
      {blog content}
     </div> <!--Closing tag for blog-->
  </div> <!--Closing tag for twelve columns-->
</div> <!--Closing tag for row-->
<div class="bgblackbottom">
 {footer content}
</div> <!--Closing tag for bgblackbottom-->
```

currently the footer is contained within the row class which is styling it as content and not a footer.

Comment: Sorry I had to give up for awhile.  Thanks for attempting to help me.  I say that only because I cant find the code you are talking about in the template.  Nowhere does it say blog in the code.  WHere can I adsd the code you have suggested?

Comment: the code that's above cannot be copied and pasted, you will have to look in your template and see the structure. The structure is what's causing the  issue and that's what needs to be changed as above.